# El resultado de la consulta no tiene sentido

Tags: sql

Estoy haciendo una consulta a una base de datos pero el resultado que me da no tiene sentido. Segun la BD hay 5 libros diferentes de los cuales hay un total de 7 ejemplares, del libro 1,3 y 5 --> 1 ejemplar del libro 2 y 4 hay 2 de cada.De prestamo tenemos que el libro 1 y 4 se ha prestado 2 veces, el libro 2 se ha prestado 3 veces y el 5 y el 3 se ha prestado 1 vez.
El enunciado de la consulta es esta

```
`A partir de dicha base de datos, se pretende crear un informe con iReport donde se reflejen por cada título los préstamos realizados de cada ejemplar incluyendo su edición. Además, por cada título se obtendrá el total de préstamos de los ejemplares que existan para dicho título.`
```

Mi consulta es

```
Select l.titulo, e.edicion, count(p.idLibro)
from Libros l, Ejemplares e, Prestamos p
where l.id = e.idLibro = p.idLibro
```

sin embargo el resultado que arroja es:

```
titulo                          edicion  count(p.idLibro)
Los pilares de la tierra          2010    14
```

No tiene sentido si igualamos los id deberian salir todo los libros no solo 1 ademas de donde cuenta 14? si el libro 1 solo se ha prestado 2 veces
en este link esta la BD
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lj0AZFDS4UajTLebL4IwBFw5GspOZl1q

Comment: Por favor usa sintaxis moderna de JOINs, disponibles desde SQL-92 (hace ya 28 años).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Desconozco que base de datos utilizas, pero según el estándar, la consulta debería ser

```
Select l.titulo, e.edicion, count(p.idLibro)
from Libros l
inner join Ejemplares e on l.id = e.idLibro
inner join Prestamos p on e.idLibro = p.idLibro
group by l.titulo, e.edicion
```

Si las claves primarias/foráneas especificadas en el `INNER JOIN` son las correcta, debería darte el número agrupado por título y edición.

**EDITO**
Si quieres limitar cualquier parámetro debes acudir al `WHERE`, si lo que quieres es limitar la agregación (en este caso el `Count`) necesitas el `HAVING`

```
Select l.titulo, e.edicion, count(p.idLibro)
from Libros l
inner join Ejemplares e on l.id = e.idLibro
inner join Prestamos p on e.idLibro = p.idLibro
Where l.id > 1
group by l.titulo, e.edicion

Select l.titulo, e.edicion, count(p.idLibro)
from Libros l
inner join Ejemplares e on l.id = e.idLibro
inner join Prestamos p on e.idLibro = p.idLibro
Where l.id > 1
group by l.titulo, e.edicion
having count(p.idLibro) > 5
```

Comment: me faltaba el group gracias. Una cosa mas tengo que meterle un parametro mas en el where el id sea igual o mayor que el que yo le diga y si le pongo Select l.titulo, e.edicion, count(p.idLibro)
from Libros l, Ejemplares e, Prestamos p
where l.id = e.idLibro = p.idLibro,e.idLibro>=1
GROUP by l.id; Me dice MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'e.idLibro>=1
GROUP by l.id LIMIT 0, 25' en la linea 3

Comment: He editado la respuesta para incluir lo que necesitas según tu comentario

Comment: porque es necesario 2 group y no vale con 1?

Comment: Si quieres contar cuantos títulos, lo agrupas por libro, si lo que quieres es contar las ediciones de cada título, necesitas agrupar por las dos. En ocasiones puede que el resultado sea el mismo, pero la forma de evitar problemas es hacerlo así.